# How to escape the = symbol in .env file

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, env-file

I try to create an application configuration with **.env** file, for the first I can get the value of variables for this config.

```
APPLICATION_NAME=MyApps
LOGGING__LOGLEVEL__DEFAULT=Warning
PROPERTY=value
```

**Result :**
[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZiRh.png)

But, when I try to add ConnectionString variable to .env file. And running my application, the value for this variable always returns **null**

```
CONNECTIONSTRINGS__CONN=Database=master;Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

**Result :**
[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItwGb.png)

I think the = symbol on `Database=master;Server=(local)` will detect as a command. Can anyone help me to explain why this happens, And how to escape the **=** symbol in .env file?

Comment: Quote the value?

Comment: the value of CONNECTIONSTRINGS_CONN is Null, but another variable in .env file is running as well